# Tracking PID in batch file and closing cmd when PID closes

Tags: windows, batch-file, process, cmd

I have a batch file that starts a HTML file from command line in whatever is the default browser:

```
start filename.html
```

I am looking for some way to find out the ID of the spawned process (firefox, ie, chrome) and track the PID in order to shut down the cmd window when the process is complete.

Basically, the process would ideally go like this: **start html, find PID of last spawned process, watch the PID, when PID closes - CMD will exit**

I have tried searching around for this and found a way to find the pid of a process but not how to track until exit.

Is it possible to do this in a BAT file? Any assistance would be lovely. Thanks!

Comment: The problem is you can not ensure the default web browser will open the html file in a new process, instead of reusing one of the existing processes and add a new tab, or a new window inside it. An this usually involves starting the a new process (your process), it talks with the existing one and sends the data required to manage the request, and the new started process (your process) ends, as all the loading of the html file is left to the old process. The new instance is dead but the file is still open in the old instance.

Comment: `start /WAIT filename.html` ?

Comment: @AlexK., i thinked (and commented) the same until i first opened a brower window and then run the command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
start filename.html
exit
```

try this. but however what i know is this that once the process is complete cmd closes on its own.

OR 
u can directly run your file without opening the cmd black window try this below script save it as example.vbs and replace testing with ur batch filename and then run this example.vbs file instead of batch file.

```
Set oShell = CreateObject ("Wscript.Shell") 
Dim strArgs
strArgs = "cmd /c testing.bat"
oShell.Run strArgs, 0, false
```